# Gradle + IntelliJ + Brew

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm attempting to load an existing gradle project in IntelliJ.  This had worked at one point but I attempted to get debugging working correctly and in the process updated things and whipped my IntelliJ project to hopefully help weirdness that was happening:
IntelliJ Version: 14.0.2
Gradle (brew installed): 2.2.1
Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_71 (Oracle Corporation 24.71-b01)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64

Attempted to import the project as a Gradle project.  It starts import then generates the following (taken from the IntelliJ log):

```
2015-01-12 14:42:46,979 [  27524]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.ProjectManager.getInstance(ProjectManager.java:40)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.findProject(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:267)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getExtraCommandLineArgs(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:240)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:144)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:63)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:363)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:335)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:214)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:95)
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:63)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.RemoteExternalSystemFacadeImpl$1.invoke(RemoteExternalSystemFacadeImpl.java:113)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.resolveProjectInfo(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

I have contacted support but mostly traded emails at this point.  I'm hoping that someone else has been through the same hell and knows the way out.  Worst case I start down revving...everything...slowly.

This is *NOT* an Android project (web services project) so I don't know why IntelliJ is throwing an error around Android.  I've attempted disabling the android plugin just for giggles with no result.

Tried doing:

```
gradle idea
```

This resulted in me getting into the project but IntelliJ still didn't know Gradle was supposed to be wired up (couldn't find packages, no gradle build, no gradle tool window, etc.).

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135107

Answer (score 0):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135107

Disabled the Android plugin.  It seems IDEA still isn't working well with Gradle.  Have other issues now but this at least gets me to the IDE.